# Largest collection of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that no set is a subset of another.

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Given a set $U$ of $n$ elements, consider a collection $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $U$ such that for all $A,B \in \mathcal{C}$, $A \not\subset B$ and $B \not\subset A$.

What is the largest possible size (or a good upper bound) of $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: This is commonly known as an _antichain_ (in the subset lattice), incidentally, and you can probably find a lot more information based around that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just [Sperner's theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) so the maximum is $${n\choose [{n\over 2}]}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If we pick $k$ with $0\le k\le n$ and let $\mathcal C$ be all the size $k$
subsets of $U$ then $\mathcal C$ satisfies your condition.

Can we do better? What does the [Lubell-Yamamoto-Meshalkin inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality) tell us?

Comment: This appears not to answer the question, for the cardinality of $\mathcal C$ depends on $k$, and the question demands that it have maximum cardinality.

Comment: @DavidSchneider-Joseph For any given $k$, though, the cardinality of $\mathcal{C}$ is easy to compute, and it's well-known which $k$ maximizes this expression...